# Can I use JSON strings in conditionals in Jade?

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

I'm new to Express/Jade and trying to noodle around and see if I can render a JSON object to a template and do some conditional logic. I'm trying to render each business name.  When I do an `each` argument, I have an undefined string because one of the businesses has one service and the other one has two.  So I want to add some conditional logic to only render the argument if its not `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
each business in data.result.businesses
     p.menu-name #{business.menuItems[0].name}
     if business.menuItems[1]
        p.menu-name #{business.menuItems[1].name}
```

You can use an `if` conditional here.